# Show $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{\log(k+1)} = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Show that
>
> $$
> \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{\log(k+1)} = 0
> $$

I have no clue how to show this. I would presume there is a clever way to use one of the $n$'s inside the sum to cancel appropriately but I can't seem to get the right idea.

Comment: Did you try Stolz-Cesaro theorem?

Comment: Use this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440333/general-cesaro-summation-with-weight  With $\lambda_k = k$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem),
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{\log(k+1)}=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{n+2}{\log(n+2)}}{(n+1)^2-n^2}
=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1+\frac{2}{n}}{(2+\frac{1}{n})\log(n+2)}=0.$$

Comment: I don't understand how to continue from this. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: @Linda Is it better now?

Comment: Yeah I get it now.Thank you!