# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\lambda_k }{a_k}\right)^{-1}= \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose that, $a_n\to \ell\neq 0$ is a converging sequence of non vanishing` complex numbers and $\{\lambda_n\}$ is a sequence of positifs real numbers such that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\lambda_k = \infty$

Then, show that, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k\right)\left(\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\frac{\lambda_k }{a_k}\right)^{-1}= \ell =\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$

I have no clue on how to start.

Comment: **Hint** : write $\ell$ as $\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \lambda_k}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\lambda_k}{\ell}}$. Notice that if $u_n\neq 0, l\neq 0$, $u_n\to l$ if and only if $\frac{1}{u_n} \to \frac{1}{l}$.

Comment: This is a sort of generalized Cesàro mean, in disguise. Relabel $b_n:=a_n^{-1}$. Then $\lim_nb_n=\ell^{-1}$ and you seek to show that
$$
{\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k b_k\over\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k}=\ell^{-1}.
$$
The special case $\lambda_n=1$ is the familiar assertion that if a sequence converges in the usual sense, then it also converges in the sense of Cesàro convergence (that is, its running averages converges). You might try this special case as a warm-up -- the proof is a pretty straightforward exercise in epsilonics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this : [General Cesaro : $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k a_k}{\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k} =\ell =\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440333/general-cesaro-summation-with-weight) to the sequence, $\frac{1}{a_n}$

we have that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k a^{-1}_k}{\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k} =\ell^{-1} =\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{-1}_n$$ 
that is 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k\right)\left(\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\frac{\lambda_k }{a_k}\right)^{-1}= \ell =\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$